Installing/Repairing SQL Server installation fails
I am installing a local instance of SQL Server.
During setup the database engine fails. What others steps can make sure the installation succeeds?
What I've tried:

Installing two times.
Repairing installation two times.
Turning off firewall.
Running installation as admin.
The database engine keeps failing. And the SQL Server service fails to start.

Am I correct to assume that this fails because the SQL Server service can't start because database engine is not installed?





Detailed results:
  Feature:                       Master Data Services
  Status:                        Passed

  Feature:                       Database Engine Services
  Status:                        Failed
  Reason for failure:            An error occurred during the setup process of the feature.
  Next Step:                     Use the following information to resolve the error, and then try the setup process again.
  Component name:                SQL Server Database Engine Services Instance Features
  Component error code:          0x84B40002
  Error description:             The SQL Server feature 'SQL_Engine_Core_Inst' is not in a supported state for repair, as it was never successfully configured. Only features from successful installations can be repaired. To continue, remove the specified SQL Server feature.

2024-05-12 00:10:43.24 Server      Microsoft SQL Server 2022 (RTM) - 16.0.1000.6 (X64) 
    Oct  8 2022 05:58:25 
    Copyright (C) 2022 Microsoft Corporation
    Developer Edition (64-bit) on Windows 10 Home Single Language 10.0 <X64> (Build 22631: ) (Hypervisor)

2024-05-12 00:10:43.24 Server      UTC adjustment: 8:00
2024-05-12 00:10:43.24 Server      (c) Microsoft Corporation.
2024-05-12 00:10:43.24 Server      All rights reserved.
2024-05-12 00:10:43.24 Server      Server process ID is 119848.
2024-05-12 00:10:43.24 Server      System Manufacturer: 'ASUSTeK COMPUTER INC.', System Model: 'ROG Strix G513QC_G513QC'.
2024-05-12 00:10:43.24 Server      Authentication mode is WINDOWS-ONLY.
2024-05-12 00:10:43.24 Server      Logging SQL Server messages in file 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL16.LOCALSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Log\ERRORLOG'.
2024-05-12 00:10:43.24 Server      The service account is 'NT Service\MSSQL$LOCALSQLSERVER'. This is an informational message; no user action is required.
2024-05-12 00:10:43.24 Server      Registry startup parameters: 
     -d C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL16.LOCALSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\master.mdf
     -e C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL16.LOCALSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Log\ERRORLOG
     -l C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL16.LOCALSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\mastlog.ldf
2024-05-12 00:10:43.24 Server      Command Line Startup Parameters:
     -s "LOCALSQLSERVER"
     -m "SqlSetup"
     -Q
     -q "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"
     -T 4022
     -T 4010
     -T 3659
     -T 3610
     -T 8015
2024-05-12 00:10:43.24 Server      SQL Server detected 1 sockets with 8 cores per socket and 16 logical processors per socket, 16 total logical processors; using 16 logical processors based on SQL Server licensing. This is an informational message; no user action is required.
2024-05-12 00:10:43.24 Server      SQL Server is starting at normal priority base (=7). This is an informational message only. No user action is required.
2024-05-12 00:10:43.24 Server      Detected 32158 MB of RAM. This is an informational message; no user action is required.
2024-05-12 00:10:43.24 Server      Using conventional memory in the memory manager.
2024-05-12 00:10:43.24 Server      Detected pause instruction latency: 65 cycles.
2024-05-12 00:10:43.24 Server      Spin divider value used: 1
2024-05-12 00:10:43.24 Server      Page exclusion bitmap is enabled.
2024-05-12 00:10:43.40 Server      Buffer Pool: Allocating 1048576 bytes for 833096 hashPages.
2024-05-12 00:10:43.40 Server      Default collation: SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS (us_english 1033)
2024-05-12 00:10:43.42 Server      Buffer pool extension is already disabled. No action is necessary.
2024-05-12 00:10:43.44 Server      CPU vectorization level(s) detected:  SSE SSE2 SSE3 SSSE3 SSE41 SSE42 AVX AVX2 POPCNT BMI1 BMI2
2024-05-12 00:10:43.44 Server      Perfmon counters for resource governor pools and groups failed to initialize and are disabled.
2024-05-12 00:10:43.46 Server      Query Store settings initialized with enabled = 1, 
2024-05-12 00:10:43.46 Server      The maximum number of dedicated administrator connections for this instance is '1'
2024-05-12 00:10:43.46 Server      This instance of SQL Server last reported using a process ID of 117212 at 12/05/2024 12:10:41 am (local) 11/05/2024 4:10:41 pm (UTC). This is an informational message only; no user action is required.
2024-05-12 00:10:43.46 Server      Node configuration: node 0: CPU mask: 0x000000000000ffff:0 Active CPU mask: 0x000000000000ffff:0. This message provides a description of the NUMA configuration for this computer. This is an informational message only. No user action is required.
2024-05-12 00:10:43.47 Server      Using dynamic lock allocation.  Initial allocation of 2500 Lock blocks and 5000 Lock Owner blocks per node.  This is an informational message only.  No user action is required.
2024-05-12 00:10:43.47 Server      Lock partitioning is enabled.  This is an informational message only. No user action is required.
2024-05-12 00:10:43.47 Server      In-Memory OLTP initialized on lowend machine.
2024-05-12 00:10:43.48 Server      [INFO] Created Extended Events session 'hkenginexesession'
2024-05-12 00:10:43.48 Server      Database Instant File Initialization: enabled. For security and performance considerations see the topic 'Database Instant File Initialization' in SQL Server Books Online. This is an informational message only. No user action is required.
2024-05-12 00:10:43.48 Server      Total Log Writer threads: 2, Node CPUs: 8, Nodes: 1, Log Writer threads per CPU: 1, Log Writer threads per Node: 2
2024-05-12 00:10:43.50 Server      Database Mirroring Transport is disabled in the endpoint configuration.
2024-05-12 00:10:43.50 Server      clwb is selected for pmem flush operation.
2024-05-12 00:10:43.50 spid42s     Warning ******************
2024-05-12 00:10:43.50 spid42s     SQL Server started in single-user mode. This an informational message only. No user action is required.
2024-05-12 00:10:43.50 Server      Software Usage Metrics is disabled.
2024-05-12 00:10:43.50 spid42s     Starting up database 'master'.
2024-05-12 00:10:43.51 spid42s     There have been 256 misaligned log IOs which required falling back to synchronous IO.  The current IO is on file C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL16.LOCALSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\master.mdf.
2024-05-12 00:10:43.51 spid42s     05/12/24 00:10:43 Stack Overflow Dump not possible - Exception c00000fd EXCEPTION_STACK_OVERFLOW at 0x00007FFE0AA1F009
2024-05-12 00:10:43.51 spid42s     SqlDumpExceptionHandler: Address=0x00007FFE0AA1F009 Exception Code = c00000fd
2024-05-12 00:10:43.51 spid42s     Rax=0000000000001118 Rbx=00000000fb49a180 Rcx=000000000741e040 Rdx=0000000008099000
2024-05-12 00:10:43.51 spid42s     Rsi=0000000008099000 Rdi=0000000000004000 Rip=000000000aa1f009 Rsp=000000004c613060
2024-05-12 00:10:43.51 spid42s     Rbp=000000004c612060 EFlags=0000000000010206
2024-05-12 00:10:43.51 spid42s     cs=0000000000000033 ss=000000000000002b ds=000000000000002b
es=000000000000002b fs=0000000000000053 gs=000000000000002b
2024-05-12 00:10:43.57 Server      CLR version v4.0.30319 loaded.
2024-05-12 00:10:43.61 Server      Common language runtime (CLR) functionality initialized using CLR version v4.0.30319 from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\.
2024-05-12 00:10:43.62 spid42s     Frame 0: 0x00007FFE07D95F16
2024-05-12 00:10:43.62 spid42s     Frame 1: 0x00007FFE08CCD6B6
2024-05-12 00:10:43.62 spid42s     Frame 2: 0x00007FFE07D958A0
2024-05-12 00:10:43.62 spid42s     Frame 3: 0x00007FFE10539C16
2024-05-12 00:10:43.62 spid42s     Frame 4: 0x00007FFE104D4BDC
2024-05-12 00:10:43.62 spid42s     Frame 5: 0x00007FFE104D4E5B
2024-05-12 00:10:43.62 spid42s     Frame 6: 0x00007FFED89DF8F5
2024-05-12 00:10:43.62 spid42s     Frame 7: 0x00007FFED89D3DA0
2024-05-12 00:10:43.62 spid42s     Frame 8: 0x00007FFED89D37A1
2024-05-12 00:10:43.62 spid42s     Frame 9: 0x00007FFED89D46EC
2024-05-12 00:10:43.62 spid42s     Frame 10: 0x00007FFED89E04B1
2024-05-12 00:10:43.62 spid42s     Frame 11: 0x00007FFEF347440F
2024-05-12 00:10:43.62 spid42s     Frame 12: 0x00007FFEF33EE466
2024-05-12 00:10:43.62 spid42s     Frame 13: 0x00007FFEF34733FE
2024-05-12 00:10:43.62 spid42s     Frame 14: 0x00007FFE0AA1F009
2024-05-12 00:10:43.62 spid42s     Frame 15: 0x00007FFE0BBBA79F
2024-05-12 00:10:43.62 spid42s     
2024-05-12 00:10:43.62 spid42s     TotalPhysicalMemory = 33720791040, AvailablePhysicalMemory = 10920484864
2024-05-12 00:10:43.62 spid42s     AvailableVirtualMemory = 140692328562688, AvailablePagingFile = 5082546176
2024-05-12 00:10:43.62 spid42s     Stack Signature for the dump is 0x00000000CFAEA995
2024-05-12 00:10:44.25 spid42s     External dump process return code 0x20000001.
External dump process returned no errors.

2024-05-12 00:10:44.27 spid42s     Unable to create stack dump file due to stack shortage (ex_terminator - Last chance exception handling)
2024-05-12 00:10:44.27 spid42s     Stack Signature for the dump is 0x0000000000000000
2024-05-12 00:10:44.27 spid42s     CDmpClient::ExecuteAllCallbacks started.
2024-05-12 00:10:44.27 spid42s     XE_DumpCallbacks is executing...
2024-05-12 00:10:44.28 spid42s     DumpCallbackSOS is executing...
2024-05-12 00:10:44.28 spid42s     DumpCallbackEE is executing...
2024-05-12 00:10:44.28 spid42s     DumpCallbackSE is executing...
2024-05-12 00:10:44.28 spid42s     DumpCallbackSEAM is executing...
2024-05-12 00:10:44.28 spid42s     DumpCallbackSSB is executing...
2024-05-12 00:10:44.30 spid42s     DumpCallbackQE is executing...
2024-05-12 00:10:44.30 spid42s     DumpCallbackFullText is executing...
2024-05-12 00:10:44.30 spid42s     DumpCallbackSQLCLR is executing...
2024-05-12 00:10:44.30 spid42s     DumpCallbackHk is executing...
2024-05-12 00:10:44.30 spid42s     DumpCallbackRepl is executing...
2024-05-12 00:10:44.30 spid42s     DumpCallbackPolyBase is executing...
2024-05-12 00:10:44.30 spid42s     CDmpClient::ExecuteAllCallbacks completed. Time elapsed: 0 seconds.
2024-05-12 00:10:44.95 spid42s     External dump process return code 0x20000001.
External dump process returned no errors.

Update :
C:\Windows\System32>fsutil fsinfo ntfsinfo C:
NTFS Volume Serial Number :        0x62906c9f906c7c03
NTFS Version      :                3.1
LFS Version       :                2.0
Total Sectors     :                950,846,094  (453.4 GB)
Total Clusters    :                118,855,761  (453.4 GB)
Free Clusters     :                 57,541,365  (219.5 GB)
Total Reserved Clusters :              663,939  (  2.5 GB)
Reserved For Storage Reserve :         655,360  (  2.5 GB)
Bytes Per Sector  :                512
Bytes Per Physical Sector :        4096
Bytes Per Cluster :                4096  (4 KB)
Bytes Per FileRecord Segment    :  1024
Clusters Per FileRecord Segment :  0
Mft Valid Data Length :            1.23 GB
Mft Start Lcn  :                   0x00000000000c0000
Mft2 Start Lcn :                   0x0000000000000002
Mft Zone Start :                   0x0000000004878280
Mft Zone End   :                   0x000000000487fc00
MFT Zone Size  :                   121.50 MB
Max Device Trim Extent Count :     256
Max Device Trim Byte Count :       0xffffffff
Max Volume Trim Extent Count :     62
Max Volume Trim Byte Count :       0x40000000
Resource Manager Identifier :      955798FB-21A8-11EC-9FBF-04421AD07687


The drive is formatted wrongly for SQL Server:
2024-05-12 00:10:43.51 spid42s     There have been 256 misaligned log IOs which 
                                   required falling back to synchronous IO.  
                                   The current IO is on file C:\Program Files\
                                   Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL16.LOCALSQLSERVER\
                                   MSSQL\DATA\master.mdf.

Bytes Per Sector  :                512
Bytes Per Physical Sector :        4096

Reformat it with 4KB clusters and reinstall Windows. Or create a new drive D: and format, then set the SQL Server database location to that.
Microsoft support policy for 4K sector hard drives in Windows.
